# JQuery verify selector ID on change

Tags: jquery, regex, select

```
$('select').change(function() {
   //important stuff
});
```

Before doing `important stuff` I want to verify the selector in question by its ID. All of the IDs I want to affect end with `_stat`. How would you do this with a regular expression (or something else) in JQuery?

```
$('select').change(function() {
   if ($("select[id*='_stat']")) {  //<~ this aint work
   //important stuff
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `if ($(this).is("select[id$='_stat']"))`, but it would surely be better to attach the event handler to these elements only in the first place -- then you wouldn't have to check at all:

```
$("select[id$='_stat']").change(function() {
   //important stuff
});
```

Comment: @Norse: Updated the answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this:

```
if($(this).is('[id$="_stat"]')) {
    // important stuff
}
```

Although if you only want the `change` handler to run on those `select` elements with ids that end in `_stat`, you should check out Jon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could even only attach to selects with id ending in _stat:

```
$('select[id$="_stat"]').change(function() {
   //important stuff only for selects id ending in _stat
});
```